# Magento - multiple price fields with specific currency

Tags: php, magento, currency

I have a challange where the products require multiple prices for multiple currency.

eg price field for GB £1   and then a second price field for Euro €1.19.

The client prefers to add these values manually rather than using conversion apis and tools,

what would be a good solution for this sort of challange

Thank you in advance

Surf

Comment: Not a question for SO since you've not even attempted to resolve it this isn't a design helping site.  Having said that your solution is simple.  Normalise your dataset and have a look up table to link currencies to items. will give you an infinite number of additional currencies per item and allow you to price items in different currencies ie: 1 item in usd, gbp the other in gbp and euro as it may not be available in america

Answer (score 1):

Magento allows to manage prices and currencies per website. You can enable it in admin configuration: `Configuration > Catalog > Price > Catalog Price Scope`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Currency Pricing system by Innoexts.

It's a module which allows you to manually set the price for each currency.

http://innoexts.com/promotion/currency-pricing/